# Sorting 2 large arrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, qsort

I have not yet taken data structures and algorithm class and I am having some troubles with what I try to do.

I have 2 large arrays, 1 is `char` with about 80k-100k words and second is `int` array with same amount of integers (for example, word written in `words[502]` has its number of occurences written in `integers[502]`).

I have to sort them so the largest integer with it's corresponding word is 1st, second largest 2nd etc etc, is it possible without using bubble sort (which is too slow for these numbers)?

```
void bubble_sort(int n)
{
    int i,j,temp;
    char tempwordy[40]={0};


    for(i=1;i< n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j< n-1;j++)
        {
            if(counters[j]>counters[j+1])
            {  
                temp=counters[j];
                counters[j]=counters[j+1];
                counters[j+1]=temp;

            strcpy(tempwordy,words[j]);
            strcpy(words[j],words[j+1]);
            strcpy(words[j+1],tempwordy);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard C library has the qsort function  to allow sorting arrays. Do not use a bubble sort.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Did you read the question?

Comment: But I have to have the integer array sorted AND make it so words from char array won't lost their value - how would I accomplish that? For example if highest integer is in integer[52] then I have to have it on first place aswell of its array aswell as words[52] first place in its array

Comment: @self  I did not feel like doing his homework today. He can consider an array of structs that are pointers to each element of the two arrays, then sort the struct array based on either "count" or word. And yes, I did read the question.  One part was: what sort algorithm to use bubble sort or other.  Other is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a structure

```
struct word
{
  char word[100];
  int count;
};

struct word array[502];
```

sort it using the `qsort` function from `stdlib.h`.

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{

const struct array *ia = (const struct array *)a;
const struct array *ib = (const struct array *)b;
if(*ia.count>*ib.count)
    return 1;
else if(*ia.count==*ib.count)
    return 0;
else
    return -1;
}
qsort(array,502,sizeof(array[0]),compare);
```

Comment: dropped bubble sort.and just change the numbers as you need

Comment: What is function compare for?

Comment: that is used by the qsort function.it compares two arguments and returns +ve -ve or 0 vakue based on the comparison.its built that way to enhance flexibility.

Comment: Ah okay, could you please tell me how to dynamically allocate memory for this struct and how to access it? For example if I want word 495 and a counter for this word, what do I write? array[495].word ?

Comment: an array is already allocated memory.if you use pointers,use malloc.you access the entries using `.` for eg,`strcpy(array[495].word,word);` or `array[495].count=5;`

Comment: Yes, I want to use pointers because otherwise it would segfault probably. So should I write something like struct word *array; and then struct word *array = malloc( sizeof( struct word )); ?

Comment: Also function compare gives me errors :< 1.c:179:7: error: request for member ‘count’ in something not a structure or union

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array of structs. First entry is the counter, second entry is the original position, and sort this (by qsort()). Thus something like

```
typedef struct _entry {
    int cnt;
    int pos;
} entry;

entry *entries;

...
/* fill the entries table */
...
qsort(...); /* or some other sort */
```

Since you're only moving two integers around, it'll be substantially faster than sorting the character array. Afterwards, you know which count belongs to which word by evaluating the position

Comment: Even better would be to store pointers to strings and instead of original positions.

Comment: It saves a redirection when retrieving the strings. So I think you're right, although the performance loss won't be huge. My way, the arrays can be built without thinking, one after the other. When storing the pointers to the strings, you'll have to build the arrays simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You adapted bubblesort to work simultaneously on two arrays. I think you can adapt many other sorting algorithms (such as e.g. [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)) to work on two arrays simultaneously. A central subroutine of quicksort is `swap` and I think that you mainly have to adjust swap and the comparison criterion such that it works on two arrays.

Another possibility would be to create a third array that "couples" a word with its occurrence. You could do this by using some kind of the following struct:

```
struct word_and_occurence {
   char** ptr_to_word;
   int occurences;
}
```

You could then sort just the array of `word_and_occurence`s and afterwards iterate over the sorted version of this array and readjust the strings properly.