# Request for member in something not a struct or union

Tags: c, function, struct, qsort

so I have function compare defined for qsort, but the following error shows:

```
1.c: In function ‘compare’:
1.c:235:7: error: request for member ‘count’ in something not a structure or union
1.c:235:17: error: request for member ‘count’ in something not a structure or union
1.c:237:12: error: request for member ‘count’ in something not a structure or union
1.c:237:23: error: request for member ‘count’ in something not a structure or union
```

Does anyone know why?  I mean it's not like I misspelled the name :<

```
struct word
{
  char wordy[100];
  int count;
};


int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{

const struct word *ia = (const struct word *)a;
const struct word *ib = (const struct word *)b;

if(*ia.count>*ib.count)
    return 1;
else if(*ia.count==*ib.count)
    return 0;
else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: And now, you've edited the original post to fix the misspelling.  In the future, copy/paste the real source - not your best recollection.

Comment: Recommend to also show your `qsort()` call.  Depending on what you want sorted, the compare function may have additional issues.

Comment: change to `(*ia).count` or `ia->count`

Comment: [rjv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258254/971127)  made ​​a mistake answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `ia` and `ib` are pointers to `const struct word`. To access a member of a structure true a pointer to it we use arrow (`->`)and not a dot `.`.

Another thing make sure to spell the structre name when you declare `ia` and `ib` the same way as you declared it in the above.

So you code whould be:

```
struct word
{
  char wordy[100];
  int count;
};


int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{

const struct word *ia = (const struct word *)a;
const struct word *ib = (const struct word *)b;

if(ia->count > ib->count)
    return 1;
else if(ia->count == ib->count)
    return 0;
else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! changing *ia.count to ia->count fixed it

Answer (score 2):

And yet, you did misspell the name :(

You're referring to `words` in the `compare` function and defining `word` outside of it.

[edit]
You say `it's defined as a global struct`.  Where?  The source you copied in here has no discoverable definition of `words`
[/edit]

**Since you've edited the post from it's original form, your problem is now as `rullof` has posted - you're accessing `->` items using `.`**

Comment: But it's defined as a global struct at the beginning of the program, and it has to be (due to other functions). edit: lmao, true about the name, but it's still the same error.

Comment: Well... The program it's in has about 10 different functions, and I wrote this struct at the beginning of the program, not in any of them - right after #include stdio.h etc, isn't that enough?

Comment: @deviance -  Read carefully what Kevin has said.  His answer is correct and points out that `words` (in the compare function) is not defined anywhere.  While globally, you have defined `word`.  Just change `words` to `word` in the compare function.

Comment: It did NOT fix the problem, error is the same after that fix.

Comment: @deviance - editing the original post while people are trying to answer your questions is confusing, and should be avoided.